# How to set a custom font and use it in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

let myPink = Color(red: 250/255, green: 114/255, blue: 100/255)
public let myHeadline = Font.custom("Lobster-Regular", size: 40,relativeTo: .title)
```

Created a custom font here⬆️

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State  var UserName:String="Eric He"
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
        Rectangle() 
                .foregroundColor(myPink)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack{
            Spacer().frame(height:70)
            HStack{
                Text("Hi,")
                    .font(myHeadline)
```

here I used my own font⬆️

```
                    .foregroundColor(myWhite)
                
            }
        Spacer()
        Navigator()
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
        
        
    }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
         
    }
}
```

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HClNa.png)

I'm a newcomer to coding, I will appreciate a lot if you could help me!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to add the font to your project.

> 1. In Xcode, select the Project navigator.
> 2. Drag your fonts from a Finder window into your project. This copies the fonts to your project.
> 3. Select the font or folder with the fonts, and verify that the files show their target membership checked for your app’s targets.
>
> - [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/applying-custom-fonts-to-text)

Apple also provides [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/) listing fonts that are installed by default.